# PHPDoc @var singleton (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, singleton, phpstorm, phpdoc

My PhpStorm can't find the method of an singleton class when I direct call it.

this works:

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
/** @var Database $db */
$this->db = $db->getDatabase(IMS_DB);
```

this not

```
/** @var Database Database::getInstance */
$this->db = Database::getInstance()->getDatabase(IMS_DB);
```

It says cannot find method `getDatabase`.

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please elaborate by giving a more detailed example and describe exactly what step you took and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: *"Any Ideas?"* yes -- you last PHPDoc is wrong -- it does not work like that. You cannot typehint some method in another class this way. Typehinting like that works for local variables (like in first place, where you typehint `$db` variable). If you need typehint return type of `Database::getInstance()` then it has to be done in that `Database` class.

Comment: Your right. @LazyOne i made a mistake at the Database Class. Set the right return type there fixed the problem. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to teach your IDE what getInstance() is actually returning, so you need to add phpDoc to **Database::getInstance()**.

```
class Database

/**
* @return self
*/
public static function getInstance(){
    //code...
}
```